# Git Bash common words

Tags: bash, git, command, command-line-interface

I would like to find a command with which i could find the common words between two text files and append them on a new text file. not all the words inlcuded, just the ones that appear on both files. Thanks in advance

To be more specific : I have 2 files. 1st is called commands.txt and 2nd is called pets.txt each of them contains 3 words.

Commands { cat ls pwd }

Pets { cat dog hamster }

What i want to do is to takethe word cat, which appears on BOTH files , and copy it to a new text file called "lovelyCommands". SOrry for the bad instructions it is my first post here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: all i have tried is the cat command but all it does is just merge the two files.. what i wanna do is to take every word that appears on both files and append it in a new file.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with either Git or bash as phrased here, but note that bash itself is a programmable command-line-interpreter, so the [tag:bash] tag would make sense if you were trying to write this *in* the programming language offered *by* bash (rather than merely using bash as a command-line interpreter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to show your efforts when posting a question. There is some **good** ways to make a question and some **bad** ones. Having said that, this will do what you intend :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} a[$1] ' file1 file2
```

And this one will do as well :

```
grep -Fxf file2 file1
```

Regards!

Comment: sorry it didnt work, neither of them. i use 

grep -Fxf file2 file1 > lovelycommands.txt and lovelycommands contain nothing

Comment: UPDATE: turns out that i had made a mistake in the part that i was entering the data in the files. as a result the contents of each file appeared on the same line, and therefore the solution couldnt work. After i correctly re arranged them it worked !!! Thanks for the response!!!!